# Erro ao tentar acessar mysql por meio de nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, linux, express.js

Estou aprendendo Nodejs, mas estou parado há algumas horas porque não consigo acessar um banco de dados mysql, como sou muito novo, não sei que problemas podem estar acontecendo.

Código:

```
//requerindo sequelize 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
//instancia de conexaão ao banco de dados 
const sequelize = new Sequelize('teste','root','',{
    host:"localhost", 
    dialect:'mysql'
})
//conexão estabelecida ou não 
sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
    console.log("conexão estabelecida!")
}).catch(function(erro){
    console.log("conexão falha! "+erro);
})
```

Esse é o erro que esta acontecendo:

> conexão falha! SequelizeConnectionError: Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando a mensagem de erro que está recebendo, podemos ver que é uma mensagem de acesso negado. Como se a senha para acessar o banco de dados estivesse errada.

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é colocando a senha correta para fazer o acesso ao banco de dados. Se usa uma instância de banco de dados sem senha, deveria utilizar o parâmetro password com o valor `NULL`.

Segue um exemplo utilizando o seu código como base:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
//instancia de conexão ao banco de dados 
const sequelize = new Sequelize('teste','root','senha-de-aceso-ao-mysql-aqui',{
    host:"localhost", 
    dialect:'mysql'
})
//conexão estabelecida ou não 
sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
    console.log("conexão estabelecida!")
}).catch(function(erro){
    console.log("conexão falha! "+erro);
})
```

Se o seu banco de dados não possui senha, basta setar o parâmetro como `null` ou pode simplesmente omitir o parâmetro.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
//instancia de conexaão ao banco de dados 
const sequelize = new Sequelize('teste','root',null,{
    host:"localhost", 
    dialect:'mysql'
})
//conexão estabelecida ou não 
sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
    console.log("conexão estabelecida!")
}).catch(function(erro){
    console.log("conexão falha! "+erro);
})
```

Mais detalhes podem ser vistos na documentação oficial do [`sequelize`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html)

Após configurar sua aplicação com sucesso, aparecerá esta mensagem:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
conexão estabelecida!
```